# LWC Need help in inserting bulk records using Lightning Web component and APEX

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, javascript, html

I am trying to insert bulk records using LWC and Apex. My data is in this format in JS -
List[{Field1:Value1, Field2: Value2}]

**APEX:**

```
public with sharing class ObjectController {
 @AuraEnabled
    public static void InsertSFFieldsMethod(String JSONFieldList) {
        List<OBJECTAPI> listOfSFFields = (List<OBJECTAPI>) JSON.deserialize(JSONFieldList, List<OBJECTAPI>.class);
        insert listOfSFFields;
    }
}
```

**JS:**

```
import INSERTFIELDS from '@salesforce/apex/ObjectController.InsertSFFieldsMethod';

export default class MapField extends LightningElement {

**HERE I AM PUSHING DATA TO MY LIST (index, Playtime, Hours are not actual field names in salesforce): **

createRow() {
        this.listOfRecs.push({ index: this.listOfmapFields.length + 1, PlayTime: null, Hours: null });
    }

**HERE I AM CALLING MY APEX METHOD AND PASSING PARAMS: calling this onclick of a button in html**

    InsertSFFields() {
        INSERTFIELDS({JSONFieldList: JSON.stringify(this.listOfRecs)
        }).then(data => {
              //my logic after success
            })
            .catch(error => {
                console.log('ERROR SAVING RECORDS');
            });
    }


}
```

Please help!!

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Hi sfdcfox, its actually not working. getting console log error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: switch console.log('ERROR SAVING RECORDS'); with console.log(error); and add the error you get to the question

Comment: @Harout - I tried and this is the error I received -
Code line:= console.log('ERROR -->' + error);
Output:= ERROR -- >[object Object]

Comment: Only console.log(error); without any string concatination

Comment: is you apex working good? i mean did you checked the logs for your apex call?

Comment: Yes. I got the error after (JSON.Stringify(error). It was because of the Required Field Missing. I had to name List columns as same name as FIeld APIs. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:

I got the error after (JSON.Stringify(error). It was because of the Required Field Missing. I had to name List columns as the same name as FIeld APIs. :)